# Issues with git and ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I get permission denied when using git clone with ssh.

I generated a new ssh-key following the instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

I've added the key with ssh-add and tried it using ssh -T git@github.com and it works. But when I try to use git clone with ssh I get permission denied.

I am using the built in OpenSSH with Windows.

Comment: You didn't mention it, but are you certain you have access to the repo in question? What command did you use (feel free to substitute "owner/repo" for that part of tha path)?

Comment: to further troubleshoot the issue, I suggest you try connecting to git@github.com using the ssh -vT git@github.com command. This command will provide you with verbose output and help identify any potential issues.

Comment: @JimRedmond I have ownership of the repo. I forgot to mention but I have another computer that does connect to the repo with ssh and I can see both keys in my ssh and gpg settings.

Comment: @borisano Thanks for the advice, I don't have access to the computer right now but I'll try that tomorrow.